# What is the combined explosive force of the Black Hole Era?

Tags: energy, cosmology, black-holes, space-expansion, big-bang

It is theorised that in the distant future all matter will gravitationally attracted into Black Holes. The universe will then be seemingly still for a long time until the Black Holes have all evaporated. They do so with an outburst of radiation at the very end. I’m interested to know what the combined explosive force is predicted to be for this? Is it the same as the Big Bang or has the universe lost energy by then?

Comment: You do realize that they wouldn’t all evaporate at the same time, right?

Comment: *It is theorised that in the distant future all matter will gravitationally attracted into Black Holes*. Where have you seen that? That's not true.

Comment: @A.V.S. - I think you are right. I think I should have said that in the Black Hole Era all the matter in the universe is inside Black Holes

Comment: @mmeent - I have to be honest and say that I did realise that but since I presumed all the explosive energy to consist of photons I didn’t think the timing would count.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is difficult to answer without knowing the exact definition of the concepts you are using.

If you define 'Universe' as the 'Universe' visible from earth, due to the gradual expansion of the universe due to lambda, by the time the Black Hole Era arrives, a lot of the energy and mass that is currently 'accessible' from Earth will have left this particular 'Universe'.

In fact, the event horizon of the universe visible from where Earth is now will, if leading theories are correct, continue to shrink around each observer until the various Planck-related limits as to how small a universe can be, are reached.

As mentioned by @mmeent, black holes will not evaporate at the same time. To answer your question, you would need to estimate the mass in the current universe as seen from earth, estimate the event horizon of the universe at the time of the Black-Hole era and reduce the combined mass and energy value of the current universe by the difference.

So, to answer your question, the universe, as seen from Earth will have lost (relatively speaking) virtually all of it's mass by the time the Black-Hole era evaporation happens. At the moment of the Big Bang, all mass currently visible from Earth and much more was within one visibility bubble. Vast quantities of that matter and energy have already left the event horizon as visible from Earth.

It seems unlikely that a new Universe could result the way you describe, as per above reasons.

Best wishes!

Comment: Thank you Estamel. I really appreciate your answer. Could you just briefly say why the event horizon of the measurable universe is going to shrink around each observer... is it due to the loss of mass?

Comment: @Wookie I could but let me just share some nice videos that will do a much better job. Check out the channel. It’s part of the reason I studied physics. https://youtu.be/AwwIFcdUFrE https://youtu.be/xZTb6sfHEX8 there’s lots of other introductory material on cosmology here :)